# Athena: Possible To Use Alias For Column?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My AWS Athena table contains a schema as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .... (  
   name STRING,
   address STRING,
   phone STRING,
   ...
)
```

However, when querying against this table I want to be able to query against `name` and for example `personName`

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS .... (  
       name STRING as personName,
       address STRING as personAddress,
       phone STRING as personPhone,
       ...
    )
```

...but I don't see how to achieve this using the documentation. (I am using Avro)

How might I achieve this without having 2 tables?

Comment: What's stoping you from simply calling it `personName` in the first place? The column name doesn't is just a reference, it doesn't actually match anything in the files. If your intention is to reference a column by two names, then this is not possible. (I've never seen any SQL system where this is supported.)

Comment: Well we could do it that way but we may need to support 2 names for a piece of data. Thanks for confirming it's not possible. I think this can now be closed

Comment: How does one change to personName? I've tried just renaming the column name when creating the table but then I get an error when I perform a SQL query

Comment: Ah! You are using Avro, so it picks up the schema from there. In that case, use the `AS` method. If you were just reading from CSV files, then you could use any name as there is no in-built schema.

Comment: Have you any example of how to achieve this? I can't find one anywhere and the above effort I have gives me an error (and the Athena errors are not always the most helpful!)

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to seek out **Presto** documentation, upon which Athena is based.